# Error Inflating Class BezelImageView in android api 16 but working in api 23?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to use the Navigation drawer from the google iosched 2015 app at [github](https://github.com/google/iosched). I have created the class my BaseActivity and the navdrawer.xml also.

I have extended the BaseActivity to my HomeActivity. The layout code for the HomeActivity is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="windo.com.wind_o.HomeScreen">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>-->



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/home_page_one"




        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            style="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/txtview1"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:background="#a0000000"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="60dp"-->
        <!--android:textSize="24sp"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"-->
        <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
        <!--android:text="WIND-O"-->
        <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
        <!--android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary" />-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

  >

        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="40dp"-->

            <!--android:text="CATEGORIES"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/transparent_with_white_border"-->

            <!--android:id="@+id/categoryBtn"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"-->
            <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
            <!--android:typeface="monospace" />-->

        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="40dp"-->
            <!--android:text="TRENDING"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/transparent_with_white_border"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/home_btn_2"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"-->
            <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
            <!--android:typeface="monospace"/>-->

        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="40dp"-->
            <!--android:text="DISCOVER"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/transparent_with_white_border"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/discover_btn"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"-->
            <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
            <!--android:typeface="monospace"/>-->
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/category_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/categoryBtn"
            android:paddingTop="15sp"

            ></Button>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            />

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trending_icon"

            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/home_btn_2"
            android:paddingTop="15sp"
            ></Button>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            />
        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/explore_icon"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/discover_btn"

            android:paddingTop="15sp"
            ></Button>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- Nav drawer -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer" />
<!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="start"-->
    <!--app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer"/>-->
```

and my navdrawer.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
   Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This layout is added to most layouts throughout the app using include directives in Activities'
     XML layouts. Google Account and Navigation Item lists are populated through BaseActivity code.
     -->
<windo.com.wind_o.views.ScrimInsetsScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/navdrawer_background"
    app:appInsetForeground="#4000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/chosen_account_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_chosen_account_height"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_cover_image_placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/navdrawer_logo_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navdrawer_logo_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/navdrawer_logo_padding_right"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:background="?colorPrimary"
                android:src="@drawable/io_logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/navview_header_default_image_content_description" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_cover_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="?colorPrimary"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/chosen_account_content_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_1">



                <windo.com.wind_o.views.BezelImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_profile_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/navdrawer_profile_image_size"
                    android:src="@drawable/person_image_empty"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:maskDrawable="@drawable/circle_mask"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/navview_start_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navview_start_padding"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navview_header_bottom_padding"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/dotted" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_email_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navview_header_bottom_padding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/body_text_2_inverse"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_name_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/profile_email_text"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/expand_account_box_indicator"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                    android:textColor="@color/body_text_1_inverse"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Account items -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/account_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/navview_account_list_top_padding"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <!-- Drawer items -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/navdrawer_items_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/navview_menu_item_top_bottom_padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/navview_menu_item_top_bottom_padding"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</windo.com.wind_o.views.ScrimInsetsScrollView>
```

Running the program on api23 works fine and everything is shown. But when I run the program on an emulator with api16 the HomeActivity throws error

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{windo.com.wind_o/windo.com.wind_o.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class windo.com.wind_o.views.BezelImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class windo.com.wind_o.views.BezelImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at windo.com.wind_o.WindoBaseActivity.setContentView(WindoBaseActivity.java:609)
    at windo.com.wind_o.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: windo.com.wind_o.views.BezelImageView
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
    at windo.com.wind_o.WindoBaseActivity.setContentView(WindoBaseActivity.java:609) 
    at windo.com.wind_o.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:32) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line 68 at which the inflate exception is shown is the BezelImageView custom view in the navdrawer.xml

Working on it for the past 2 days but can't figure out why it works in  api 23 but not on api 16?

Edit: Code for BezelImageView

```
package windo.com.wind_o.views;

/**
 * Borrowed from google iosched
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import windo.com.wind_o.R;


/**
 * An {@link android.widget.ImageView} that draws its contents inside a mask and draws a border
 * drawable on top. This is useful for applying a beveled look to image contents, but is also
 * flexible enough for use with other desired aesthetics.
 */
public class BezelImageView extends ImageView {
    private Paint mBlackPaint;
    private Paint mMaskedPaint;

    private Rect mBounds;
    private RectF mBoundsF;

    private Drawable mBorderDrawable;
    private Drawable mMaskDrawable;

    private ColorMatrixColorFilter mDesaturateColorFilter;
    private boolean mDesaturateOnPress = false;

    private boolean mCacheValid = false;
    private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
    private int mCachedWidth;
    private int mCachedHeight;

    public BezelImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public BezelImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BezelImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Attribute initialization.
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BezelImageView,
                defStyle, 0);

        mMaskDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.BezelImageView_maskDrawable);
        if (mMaskDrawable != null) {
            mMaskDrawable.setCallback(this);
        }

        mBorderDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.BezelImageView_borderDrawable);
        if (mBorderDrawable != null) {
            mBorderDrawable.setCallback(this);
        }

        mDesaturateOnPress = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.BezelImageView_desaturateOnPress,
                mDesaturateOnPress);

        a.recycle();

        // Other initialization.
        mBlackPaint = new Paint();
        mBlackPaint.setColor(0xff000000);

        mMaskedPaint = new Paint();
        mMaskedPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        // Always want a cache allocated.
        mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        if (mDesaturateOnPress) {
            // Create a desaturate color filter for pressed state.
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(0);
            mDesaturateColorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final boolean changed = super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
        mBounds = new Rect(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        mBoundsF = new RectF(mBounds);

        if (mBorderDrawable != null) {
            mBorderDrawable.setBounds(mBounds);
        }
        if (mMaskDrawable != null) {
            mMaskDrawable.setBounds(mBounds);
        }

        if (changed) {
            mCacheValid = false;
        }

        return changed;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBounds == null) {
            return;
        }

        int width = mBounds.width();
        int height = mBounds.height();

        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (!mCacheValid || width != mCachedWidth || height != mCachedHeight) {
            // Need to redraw the cache.
            if (width == mCachedWidth && height == mCachedHeight) {
                // Have a correct-sized bitmap cache already allocated. Just erase it.
                mCacheBitmap.eraseColor(0);
            } else {
                // Allocate a new bitmap with the correct dimensions.
                mCacheBitmap.recycle();
                //noinspection AndroidLintDrawAllocation
                mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                mCachedWidth = width;
                mCachedHeight = height;
            }

            Canvas cacheCanvas = new Canvas(mCacheBitmap);
            if (mMaskDrawable != null) {
                int sc = cacheCanvas.save();
                mMaskDrawable.draw(cacheCanvas);
                mMaskedPaint.setColorFilter((mDesaturateOnPress && isPressed())
                        ? mDesaturateColorFilter : null);
                cacheCanvas.saveLayer(mBoundsF, mMaskedPaint,
                        Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
                super.onDraw(cacheCanvas);
                cacheCanvas.restoreToCount(sc);
            } else if (mDesaturateOnPress && isPressed()) {
                int sc = cacheCanvas.save();
                cacheCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, mCachedWidth, mCachedHeight, mBlackPaint);
                mMaskedPaint.setColorFilter(mDesaturateColorFilter);
                cacheCanvas.saveLayer(mBoundsF, mMaskedPaint,
                        Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
                super.onDraw(cacheCanvas);
                cacheCanvas.restoreToCount(sc);
            } else {
                super.onDraw(cacheCanvas);
            }

            if (mBorderDrawable != null) {
                mBorderDrawable.draw(cacheCanvas);
            }
        }

        // Draw from cache.
        canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, mBounds.left, mBounds.top, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        if (mBorderDrawable != null && mBorderDrawable.isStateful()) {
            mBorderDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
        }
        if (mMaskDrawable != null && mMaskDrawable.isStateful()) {
            mMaskDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
        }
        if (isDuplicateParentStateEnabled()) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        if (who == mBorderDrawable || who == mMaskDrawable) {
            invalidate();
        } else {
            super.invalidateDrawable(who);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
        return who == mBorderDrawable || who == mMaskDrawable || super.verifyDrawable(who);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code of BeizelImageView

Comment: @Raghunandan updated

Comment: i don't see a problem with the bezelimageview. You can check if there are any deprecated methods. but that should be a warning not  a  crash

Comment: The android studio doesn't show any deprecated method. Neither there are any significant warning.

Comment: The exception's root cause is Class Not found. But  why is it that? The class is just sitting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got the hang of the problem. 
The error was inflating view because the app cannot find the Class `BezelImageView`.
There was another custom view in my app and it was also throwing the same error.

The class existed but the app was unable to find it. I unzipped my apk file and found that there were 2 dex files : **classes.dex**, **classes2.dex** and my `CustomeView`s are in classes2.dex file.

Upon more inspection the problem was that below android 5 the app was unable to load classes from **classes2.dex** . Since Android L by default loads the classes from all dex files because of new Runtime Environment ART, hence my app was working fine on and above Android L.

To make the classes load from all files I have to do following things

1. add the multidex library in my build.gradle as

   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
2. Override `attachBaseContext` in my Application Class as

   `protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }`

and now all the classes from dex files are correctly found on app below android L.

If you do not extend the application class then you can just add the following line in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<application
...
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"/>
...
```

The above steps can be found at [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)